# Cassandra-Driver error, can't run Python scripts

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra, pip, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-driver

**Background**

I've been trying to run a couple Python scripts on a server for a while now, however I receive the following error every time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "config.py", line 1, in <module>
        from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
ImportError: No module named cassandra.cluster
```

I'm assuming this has to do with the Cassandra-Driver not being installed, however when I run:

```
pip install cassandra-driver
```

I receive the following output:

```
Collecting cassandra-driver
Requirement already satisfied: futures in /home/ubilab/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cassandra-driver) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cassandra-driver) (1.11.0)
Installing collected packages: cassandra-driver
Successfully installed cassandra-driver-3.16.0
```

**Problem**

I'm assuming that the driver has now been installed, but when I go to run the script again, I receive a new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "config.py", line 1, in <module>
        from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

I'm not sure how to fix it or another alternative for downloading the driver? If anyone has come across this error, what were you able to do to solve it? I've removed the directory with the error, however if I remove it, my script breaks since it needs Cassandra to load data to. Any input would be great.

**More Background Info**

- Running on Ubuntu 18.04
- Using Python 2.7
- Using Cassandra 3.11.1

Thanks,
A struggling Software Developer :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should give a try reinstalling Cassandra-driver with:

```
pip install cassandra-driver --no-binary :all:
```

Comment: I'll try that out -- I've tried installing a different version of the driver but all it caused some errors with my Protocol Version. I believe I'm only having a problem with the 3.16 version of the driver.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some conflicting packages in:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.so
```

undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf error is caused due to broken packages in a directory

In order to solve this issue cd to cassandra directory and remove that folder.
You can follow this:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra
sudo rm -rf cluster.so
```

This will solve the issue.